# git interactive rebase - edit vs break

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I've tried googling this but wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer.

I'd like to know what the difference is between `edit` and `break` in the interactive mode of `git rebase -i`.

According to the comments, `edit` uses the commit, but stops for amending, while `break` stops at the specified location. But then what is the difference between:

```
# Scenario 1

pick a9ca198 commit #1
pick 15948d1 commit #2
edit 2dbe941 commit #3  // this will apply commit #3 and then stop.
pick 33c012d commit #4
```

```
# Scenario 2

pick a9ca198 commit #1
pick 15948d1 commit #2
pick 2dbe941 commit #3
break                   // this will stop after commit #3
pick 33c012d commit #4
```

I've tried them both and to me, they seem to be completely identical.

Comment: Weird, I don't have the `break` option on git version 2.17.1

Comment: @MickaelB. Oh maybe `break` is a command that's been only added recently. My version is 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128).

Comment: @SeminPark Yes, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode) mentions:

> To interrupt the rebase (just like an "`edit`" command would do, but without cherry-picking any commit first), use the "`break`" command.

In your case, the differences are:

- with `edit` on commit 3, you can still amend the files content of commit 3 (after applying commit 3), commit (still commit 3, but modified/amended), and go on applying (cherry-picking) commit 4 on a `git rebase --continue`.
- with `break` after commit 3, commit 4 will not be applied. And commit 3 is already applied (if you change the files at at point, add and commit, that would create a new commit, unless you do a `git commit --amend`).

So the main difference is:

- `edit`: apply the commit 3, but allows you to modify the end result. Then resume and apply commit 4.
- `break`: do not apply the commit 4 (apply it only when you resume the rebase)

If `break` is alone on its line, then yes, it can be similar to `edit` on commit 3, provided you do a `git commit --amend` (since commit 3 was already cherry-picked in the previous line)

But then the `git rebase --continue` (after the `add`+`commit --amend`) will stop, because of said `break`.

As [DylanYoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3124256/dylanyoung) puts it in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969425/git-interactive-rebase-edit-vs-break/62969493#comment111380211_62969493):

> It allows you to break immediately after an `exec` or `merge`, which was not possible before.

---

Note: `edit` was introduced with an interactive rebase in [Git v1.5.3-rc0, June 2007, commit 1b1dce4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b1dce4bae760248a1fc3e29548a72c446e77270).

But the command `break` alone is much more recent: [Git v2.20.0-rc0, Oct. 2018, commit 71f8246](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71f82465b1c9546a09c442c3c9aa22ecbb76f820)

See [commit 71f8246](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71f82465b1c9546a09c442c3c9aa22ecbb76f820) (12 Oct 2018), and [commit b8c0b21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8c0b2100bbcbbfe324962b0f15c92207d945895) (10 Oct 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 789b1f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/789b1f70422d5c9ffb3a0ecb11284aa0ac13985e), 02 Nov 2018)</sup>

> "`git rebase -i`" learned a new instruction ("insn"), '`break`', that the user can insert in the to-do list.
> Upon hitting it, the command returns control back to the user.

> ### `rebase -i`: introduce the '`break`' command
>
> The '`edit`' command can be used to cherry-pick a commit and then
> immediately drop out of the interactive rebase, with exit code 0, to let
> the user amend the commit, or test it, or look around.
>
> Sometimes this functionality would come in handy *without*
> cherry-picking a commit, e.g. to interrupt the interactive rebase even
> before cherry-picking a commit, or immediately after an '`exec`' or a
> '`merge`'.
>
> This commit introduces that functionality, as the spanking new '`break`'
> command.

---

See ["Give me a break"... well, you gave me one](https://public-inbox.org/git/nycvar.QRO.7.76.6.1904011724550.41@tvgsbejvaqbjf.bet/T/#u):

> Just wanted to express my gratitude for your idea to introduce the `break`
> command in `git rebase -i`'s todo list. I use it *all* the time now.
>
> Before that, I was using `x bash`, and ended up doing `git rebase --continue` in that shell in many cases, which didn't end up so well
> when I terminated said shell (just an error message, though, nothing
> actually broke as a consequence). This feature is a blessing.

Or:

> '`x bash`' will start another shell, that seems an odd thing to do.
>
> I have been using '`x false`' to generate an error exit status to interrupt
> the rebase and drop into the current shell.
> Then '`git rebase --continue`' to resume.
>
> `b` is much shorter to type than `x false` (and I also cannot
> tyop it late at night as `x flase`, although that would have the same
> effect, I guess, of stopping the interactive rebase).

Comment: But in my examples, if I `break` after a commit, I can amend or change the previous commit in anyway just like I would with `edit`ing the previous commit. Is there anything that I cannot do with a `break`, but can with an `edit` or vice versa?

Comment: @SeminPark Genrally, break is not used alone, but in a line with a commit (meaning on commit 4, to avoid applying it): that is where the difference is. If you use it alone, then yes, it is like an edit on commit 3.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in a line with a commit". I've tried `break 2dbe941 commit #3` during `git rebase -i` and git is complaining "error: break does not accept arguments: '2dbe941 commit #3". Could you provide an example where `break` is used in a line with a commit?

Comment: @SeminPark I agree: that has changed recently, hence my edit.

Comment: @SeminPark yes. The difference is how you amend commit 3. If you don't need to amend commit 3, but simply stop before commit 4: break. If you do need to amend commit 3, edit on commit 3.

Comment: Oh saw your edited answer just now and deleted my last comment. I get it now! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I still don't see how this is a significant difference.  One nice thing is it allows you to edit the commit before the first one that shows up in the TODO list (a common complaint about rebase), but other than that, what does this change?  Does it affect the input to post-rewrite hook?

Comment: @DylanYoung It is clearer than artificially edit the previous commit to make the rebase stop.

Comment: I guess if you aren't familiar with how rebase works, it would be clearer :)

Comment: I figured it out after looking at the commit https://github.com/git/git/commit/71f82465b1c9546a09c442c3c9aa22ecbb76f820.  It allows you to break immediately after an `exec` or `merge`, which was not possible before (this is already in the answer, but I must have skipped over it).

Comment: @VonC a thing that does not become clear from your answer: `edit` allows the commit to be modified *without committing* again. So you just modify, `git add` and `git rebase --continue`. `break` would require a `git add` and a `git commit --amend` to achieve the same.

Comment: @AplusKminus Why add and commit --amend after a break? Without any pending change, all previous commits are already applied.

Comment: Assumed use case: I want to modify commit3. If I use `edit commit3`, I can modify, `git add` and `git rebase --continue`. If I use `pick commit3\nbreak`, I can modify, `git add`, must do `git commit --amend` and then `git rebase --continue`. That is the difference I wanted to highlight.

Comment: @AplusKminus Or, if you want to modify commit 3 and stop there: `edit` + `break`. You will `add`+`commit`+`rebase --continue`,  which will then promptly stop, because of the `break`.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I use `break` for that `edit` cannot do is apply a `fixup` and then do something else, like update a code review.

E.g. if I have

```
pick commit1 feature x
pick commit2 feature y
pick commit3 fixup for feature x
```

I can

```
$ git rebase --interactive
```

```
pick commit1 feature x
fixup commit3 fixup for feature x
break
pick commit2 feature y
```

then

```
$ command-to-update-cr
$ git rebase --continue
```

Note that you could use `exec` for the same purpose, but I prefer the control I get from getting dropped into the command line.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you provide, you are correct.  Using `break` after `pick` is identical to just using `edit`.  It doesn't make sense to use `break` this way.  Where `break` becomes useful is when it follows `squash`, `fixup`, `merge`, or `exec`.

This is explained in [the commit message that introduced the `break` command](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71f82465b1c9546a09c442c3c9aa22ecbb76f820):

> #### rebase -i: introduce the 'break' command
>
> The `edit` command can be used to cherry-pick a commit and then
> immediately drop out of the interactive rebase, with exit code 0, to let
> the user amend the commit, or test it, or look around.
>
> Sometimes this functionality would come in handy *without*
> cherry-picking a commit, e.g. to interrupt the interactive rebase even
> before cherry-picking a commit, or immediately after an `exec` or a
> `merge`.
>
> This commit introduces that functionality, as the spanking new `break`
> command.

Comment: But it sounds like `break` supercedes the value of edit. I.e. you can do everything you would otherwise want to do with edit with `break` but not vice versa. I suppose though that they weren't going to remove the `edit` feature/command so they left both?

Comment: Right.  Removing `edit` would be a breaking change with no real benefit, so that wouldn't be an option worth pursuing.  Also, and this may be a stretch, perhaps `edit` is more intuitive than `pick` followed by `break`.

Answer (score 3):

Much shorter answer:

`break` allows you to do everything edit does, but was introduced > 10 years after `edit` so `edit` still exists.

`edit` has the very mild advantage of implying `git commit --amend` on `git rebase --continue`.